# VueJS Compiles Production with Syntax Error

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli (v2). The dev build works fine, but when I compile to production (npm run build), Chrome is throwing a syntax error in the vendor js file.

I don't even know where to start with debugging this. Help!

**Error:**
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (/static/js/vendor.bcf4af616d173011918b.js)

Update: It looks like the JS file is being truncated for some reason. How to fix this?